# How to make rounded background with drawable in XML Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to make rounded image background using XML but could not figure it out. I tried with a layer-list and read various articles but could not figure out the mistake.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <solid
                android:color="#fcfcfc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bg">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here's what the output looks like for the above code:

[image: Output received for drawable XML when tried to make rounded background]

I wanted the image to be rounded.

```kotlin
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_drawingViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_drawing_view_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:contentDescription="image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.pranjallabs.inkwell.DrawingView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawing_view"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are many ways to achieve this like

- Use Cardview
- Use some libraries like https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView
- Using `shape` xml
- Using `ShapeableImageView`
- Using Glide also

Using shape you can achieve like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    ...
</shape>
```

In your activity or fragment: `ImageView.setClipToOutline(true)`

Using ShapeableImageView

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageViewRounded"
    app:strokeColor="@color/....."
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    ...
    />
```

in xml

```
<style name="roundedImageViewRounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```